# How to measure the amount of light emitted back from a fiber optic cable?

Tags: laser, sampling, optical-fibre

I would like to build a setup where I use a light source to emit a signal over a fiber optic cable, and then measure the amount of light that is emitted back, e.g. by blocking/opening the other end of the cable with my thumb. How could I build such a system?

Comment: This is a research question and probably too broad, the first thing you'd need is some optical engineers. My advice would be to use a sensor that measures deflection based on position.

Comment: I think this kind of devices have been done in the past, it is just that there's really no big markets for them (thus no suppliers). I think I could do it if I somehow first got a proper idea which parts already exist in some form

Comment: hmm, ok, well would it help if we narrow this just to "how to measure back-emitted light from a fiber optic cable"? (or along those lines)

Comment: Maybe look up self-mixing interferometry https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUdro-6u2Zg Make sure to look in the video description for a link to a paper. You don't need to do self-mixing, but if you don't then you need a bunch of optical components and crystals to split the laser and mix it back onto itself and re-direct it towards an external photodiode. Don't forget laser safety goggles in your budget.

Comment: Thank @DKNguyen, I'll have a look

Comment: Do you need to measure the reflection from the far end of the fiber separately from the reflection off the near end of the fiber?

Comment: For non-self mixing interferometry, the key optical component (which I did not even know existed or was even possible until I looked into it pretty hard) is called an "optical circulator" that lets a laser entering port A exit through port B, but light entering port B exits through port C. In this way, it lets the beam mix onto itself but then splits it away from the emitter so it can be re-directed towards an external photodiode.

Comment: I routinely use a beam-splitter arrangement for something similar. The differences may be that the emitted and received wavelengths are different due to fluorescence or phosphorescence. This makes it easy with dichroics. Please provide much more disclosure about what exactly you are doing.